# Ubuntu 18.04 Doesn't Use My GPU (GTX1650), Also I can't connect any Second Monitor from HDMI Port

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, hdmi

I know that there are some other questions similar but I haven't been able to find the solution from them so I'm asking again. I have Nvidia GTX 1650 and Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted with Windows 11 (Secure boot disabled). I am using Nvidia-driver-470 and kernel 5.19. Ubuntu says my graphics card is "llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits)"

Also as I stated in the headline, I can't connect any second monitor via hdmi port but I think that it is related with the graphics card issue.

I have "quiet splash nomodeset" in my /etc/default/grub this might be the issue but I can't get anything but black screen when I delete nomodeset from it. Does anyone have any solution? Thanks for all your answers in advance.

This is the output of “lshw -C display”:

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           version: a1
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
      *-display UNCLAIMED
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: Cezanne
           vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           version: c5
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc57ffff
```

This is the output of " lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D":

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 150c
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
--
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c5)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 150c
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: "I am using Nvidia-driver-470 and kernel 5.19". No you aren't. Because you're using an out of band kernel the Nvidia drivers aren't compiling correctly. And whenever you add `nomodeset` no drivers are loaded, period, regardless of properly installed or not, hence the "unclaimed" status. Without the drivers properly loaded the outputs for external monitors won't work. That's all

Comment: Okay, but I cant launch without using nomodeset. It just stucks in black screen while booting. Do you know any solution for it?

Comment: That was my 2nd second above. Plus you're using and almost out of support release with an out of band kernel, nonsensical. Try the current 22.04 without changing the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same problem as I do and doesn't understand how ubuntu works, I am posting the steps which worked for me:
First of all, I was using an incompatible kernel so I upgraded it with using liquorix kernel.
After that, I removed "nomodeset" from kernel parameter.
And lastly, I upgraded my firmware manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/jammy-updates/linux-firmware.
This solution was provided by generix in nvidia forums to me. So all credit goes to him/her actually. Have a nice day you all :)